# Visual Code conflict between 'clangd' and 'C/C++ IntelliSense'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, intellisense

In Visual Code version 1.82.2, if I enable 'clangd' 0.1.26 and 'C/C++ IntelliSense' 1.18.5, along with 'C/C++ Extension Pack' 1.3.0, I get code completion, but not 'go to definition' and 'go to declaration'. If I invert the extensions, I also invert what works.

'Clang-format' 1.9.0 formats the code correctly with any of the extensions.

How can I get code completion and 'go to definition' and 'go to declaration' work in Visual Code?

Comment: what is the "C/C++ intellisense" extension? You mean https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools ? because if that's what you're asking about, this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Clangd and the C++ Extension will fight over intellisense / code completion as they both try to do the same task at the same time.  You will need to diable intellisense for the C++ Extension by adding the following line to your settings.json file:

```
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Disabled",
```

Clangd will handle the intellisense / code completion task along with "Go to definition".  C++ Extension will handle other things like debugging.